# Is a native request in springboot

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have this error when I execute my following native request:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 5' at line 1.
```

I don't see any problems please help me.
My code:

```
@Repository
public interface AdherentRepository extends JpaRepository<Adherent, Long> {
public Iterable<Adherent> findByEmpruntsIdemprunt(Long Id);


@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM adherent WHERE nom LIKE :x OR email LIKE :x OR matricule LIKE :x ;", nativeQuery = true)
public Page<Adherent> findAdherent(@Param("x") String x, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: maybe wrong dialect?

Comment: Is it just the semicolon at the end of the query string? It looks like you want the system to give you a paginated result set; this is usually done by adding a "limit x offset y" to the query to get MySQL to return only the portion of the result set that you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to return a list and turn this list into page at the controller level